# Is it against the rules to link from my own, monetized site to a question or answer on SE?

Tags: support, licensing

I want to document my progress on various projects and, as part of that documentation, I want to publish the questions I ask on the various SE sites. The website will be monetized. The questions I ask would be a search criteria and would link back to this site. Links to SE from my site would highlight my question and the answer I choose, or the user whose answer I chose. Even if there is no answer, I would link to a question that illustrates my methodology/thought process at a given time during a project's creation

Comment: If it's content you wrote you can do whatever you want with it, or are you proposing to copy other people's work onto your site too?

Comment: What purpose would the links to your site be serving, for the questions on SE?

Comment: No, all published work would be original. The links would just be to show my thinking over time and display other people's answers. Also, if the answer's content proves to be essential, I could cite the question or the user's profile, directly. The latter seems less useful.

Comment: I would use the SE sites to ask questions one would normally ask a professor, whom I have no access to. I rely on this site and would like to showcase as much. All work will be attributed to the appropriate parties. I just want to make sure I wouldn't be breaking rules.

Comment: It's unclear to me if your question here is asking about you are planning to link from SE to your site or from your site to SE. Perhaps that's just my bias against spam (which would primarily be about linking from SE to your site). Upon additional reads of your question it's sounding more as if you're asking about linking from your site to SE. Please clarify. I think that a large part of my confusion is that your title says linking to your site, whereas the body implies linking from your site (implying the title might just be poor wording).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do what you like with content that you write and publish here. You're only licencing it to Stack Exchange, you can publish it elsewhere too with whatever licence you want.

If you take any other content from here though i.e. other people's contributions then you would need to [licence that correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing).

If you only link back to this site whenever you have external content, that would be OK too i.e. you display your question directly on your site licenced in any way you like with a link to any/all answers because you're not hosting any content from Stack Exchange on your site in that case.

There are some questions and answers on this subject from [Stack Overflow's Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) that are probably worth a read.

- [Is it valid if one licenses their own answer at Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291319/is-it-valid-if-one-licenses-their-own-answer-at-stack-overflow)
- [Does Stackoverflow's code licensing override my previously specified license?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315413/does-stackoverflows-code-licensing-override-my-previously-specified-license)

Comment: Bear in mind, if the content is not up to the standards of whichever Stack Exchange site you post it on, it may get downvoted or deleted. It could also be edited to bring it in line with style and tagging conventions, but this will usually not change the actual meaning of the post.

Comment: Links to the answer of any question I ask would be directed to the person who answered the question. It just seems more relevant and useful to link to the question, itself, and the approved answer.

Comment: Under no circumstances would I need to link to someone's code unless it was an answer to a question I asked that, too, contained code. Most of my questions will be directed toward the mathematics, economics, etc. stacks, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your workflow is:

- Create question and/or answer on Stack Overflow
- Repost said question and/or answer on your own site *with* attribution
- Own site would be essentially a paywall or otherwise monetized (ads)

IANAL, but [this sounds like it'd be in line with CC-by-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode).  If you failed to attribute, then you would be in violation of the license.

Comment: Why attribution if the OP is the author?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards:  Because CC-by-SA doesn't explicitly carve that out and there is this weird thing called [self-plagiarism](https://www.aje.com/arc/self-plagiarism-how-to-define-it-and-why-to-avoid-it/) which can make enforcing the letter of the law trickier than the spirit of the law (remember, laws are as written, not as read).

Comment: IIUC the OP licenses their content under CC-by-SA to SE and its users. Being the copyright holder, they are free to use their content in whatever manner they please (assuming no edits from other users, etc.).

Comment: @GoodDeeds:  So...in that case, it's just a lot easier to just attribute *yourself* then, isn't it?  Also link to the original content as required by the license.  This way there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Of course it is a good idea to attribute, but it is not _required_, in this scenario. My point was that the license _does not apply to the OP_ if they are the sole copyright holder, they are the one granting the license to others, including SE. (See e.g. https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/5913)

Comment: By posting on you own site you are attributing yourself... the licensee _needs_ to attribute not the licensor, which the OP clearly is in this situation. If I create the question in a text editor and copy and paste it into SO does the OP have to attribute themselves on SO too?